# Image capturing issue in HTC mobile

Tags: android, camera, htc-android

i am using following code for capturing the image in Android:

```
String fileName = "image.jpeg";
                //create parameters for Intent with filename
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION,"Image captured by camera");
                //imageUri is the current activity attribute, define and save it for later usage (also in onSaveInstanceState)
                imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
                //create new Intent
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
```

After capturing the image, i am using following code to get image:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
        {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                            if( requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST)
                {
                    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
                    {
                        if(imageUri == null)
                            imageUri = data.getData();
                        String filePath = getPath(imageUri);
                        UploadContentToServer(filePath, "image.jpeg");
                        //getBytesFromFile(filePath);
                    }
                }
}
```

It works fine in all devices except HTC in landscape mode.

I am using **portrait** mode in my app. But when i capture a image in landscape mode in my HTC,i am getting **imageUri** null.
How to resolve this issue, it is only in HTC devices.

Comment: have you got any force close when your device in landscape mode?

Comment: no, actually in app i have set the orientation portrait, only the imageUri is null

Comment: hi sandy i have one more question if ur device is in portrait mode did u get the imageUri?

Comment: Yes, even if i capture image in landscape mode and i press OK on captured image in portrait mode, then also i get the imageUri.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue on my galaxy s2 when trying to capture images with the camera. Try specifying the real path in the intent and then get the path down in your onActivityResult. Extracting the uri directly from the Intent data didnt work for me in image capture either.

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
 SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss");
 fileName = dateFormat.format(new Date()) + ".jpg";
 File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), fileName);
 Intent cameraintent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
 cameraintent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
 imageURICamera = Uri.fromFile(photo);
 startActivityForResult(cameraintent, 1);
```

And now getting the foto again in onActivityResult:

```
 realPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + fileName;
```

Answer (score 0):

For HTC Desire HD, the following method worked.

```
protected Uri createUriFromPhotoIntentForHtcDesireHD( Intent intent, Uri uri ) {
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getExtras().get( "data" );
        File outputDir = getCacheDir();
        File outputFile = File.createTempFile( "Photo-", ".jpg", outputDir );
        fos = new FileOutputStream( outputFile );
        bitmap.compress( Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fos );
        uri = Uri.fromFile( outputFile );
    } catch ( IOException e ) {
        Ln.e( e, "Error creating temp file for HTC Desire HD" );
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if ( fos != null ) {
                fos.close();
            }
        } catch ( IOException e ) {
            Ln.e( e, "Error closing temp file for HTC Desire HD" );
        }
    }
    return uri;
}
```